# React js form field names and refs with concatenation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Hi I am trying to concatenate form field names and refs like this and returning the jsx

```
<select className="lp-country" id="lp-country" name = 'country'{i} ref = 'country'{i} >
```

where i is the index of the loop. I am getting unexpected token error.

Code screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/8QILiZaBGMM

Error screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/ITZPH6BVT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is not used correctly there.

replace

```
name = 'country'{i}
```

with

```
name = {`country${i}`}
```

Same for `ref`.

Comment: perfect! glad I could help : - )